# regist servicestack without permission?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

i can regist servicestack register service like

```
 var responseX =
                    client.Post(new Register
                    {

                        UserName = sicil.Text,
                        Password = Password.Text,
                        FirstName = adX.Text,
                        LastName = soyadX.Text,
                        Email = sicil.Text,
                        AutoLogin = false,
                        Continue = "",
                        DisplayName =adX.Text+ " "+ soyadX.Text
                    });
```

and also i can register from rest services, but i want only auth users can register or apply

is there something way to

[Auth]
Register

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add attributes to any `Type` or `Property` in ServiceStack with the [runtime attribute API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RuntimeAttributeTests.cs) which lets you modify the attributes of any built-in Services, e.g:

```
typeof(Register)
    .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
```

Comment: i will use it at global.asax? i just want only auth users can add or send request, and i wonder, is there possible to change registered user data? if its how? i can only send register

Comment: @Haluk you can also resolve and use the [IAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs) directly like any normal dependency, or depending what AuthRepository you're using directly access the [UserAuth POCO Tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs) with OrmLite.